# How do I get the next json key?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, indexing

There is such a json:

```
{
    "id": "1994",
    "schedule": {
        "1": {
            "title": "Понедельник",
            "schedule": {
                "4": {
                    "1": {
```

Full: https://pastebin.com/wLX6D0wG

I output schedule['schedule']['1']['schedule'], but how do I get the next key (the json file can change, and the key value too. In this case, it is equal to 4)?

Using an index? How?

Comment: Your dict is invalid. Please verify it

Comment: @azro I think this is supposed to be a json file and not a dict.

Comment: @kinshukdua That doesn't change anything, Valid dict or valid json, same

Comment: `id_users` should probably be an array of objects.

Comment: @azro Oh, sorry. Here is my real json (https://pastebin.com/wLX6D0wG). I output `schedule['schedule']['1']['schedule']`, but I don't know how to get the next key, since it may differ from

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
jsn = {
    "id": "1994",
    "schedule": {
        "1": {
            "title": "LOL",
            "schedule": {
                "4": {
                    "1": {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# dumping jsn variable from !!!PYTHON!!! dict to string
step_one = json.dumps(jsn)
# loading dumped jsn variable from string to !!!JSON!!!
step_two = json.loads(step_one)

print(step_two['schedule']['1'])
print(step_two['schedule']['1']['schedule'])
print(step_two['schedule']['1']['schedule']['4'])
print(step_two['schedule']['1']['schedule']['4']['1'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. This is  `schedule['schedule'][str(weekday_list.get(dayWeek))]['schedule'].keys()`